# I can't find my public interfaces

Tags: networking, internet, 22.04, iptables, netcat

I need to port forward my Ubuntu 22.04 desktop, so I can establish remote shell between my home desktop and my portatil; which should be with this topology: `ip public:8443 => ip private ip:8443`. But the problem is I can't find the Public. I use the command: ip -4 addr show scope global, and his output was:

```
3: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel
state UP group default qlen 1000 inet 192.168.1.13/24 brd
192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp3s0 valid_lft 83594sec preferred_lft 83594sec
```

As you can see, the public interfaces don't show up anywhere. I type `ipconfig` and return me the following output:

```
enp12s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether c4:da:26:05:9b:0d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
 
 lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
         inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
         inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
         loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Bucle local)
         RX packets 5817  bytes 596148 (596.1 KB)
         RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
         TX packets 5817  bytes 596148 (596.1 KB)
         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
 
 wlp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
         inet 192.168.1.13  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
         inet6 fe80::e117:5f6c:37e7:1e7b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
         ether 0c:84:dc:cf:a1:69  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
         RX packets 22905  bytes 14053525 (14.0 MB)
         RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 429967
         TX packets 23292  bytes 4002863 (4.0 MB)
         TX errors 154  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
         device interrupt 17
```

and only appears one interfaces which is the private interfaces(wlp3s0) and with the command: ip route show | grep default

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp3s0 proto dhcp metric 600
```

return me the private adreses as the public adresses

Do you know how to solve this error? How can I find or install the public interfaces

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to determine your router's public IP address:

1. Login to your router's admin interface.
2. Ask some other server on the internet what your origin IP address appears to be. For example, try Googling "*What is my IP address?*" and Google will reveal your public IP address.

You cannot directly determine the public IP address from within the LAN *because you're on the wrong network*. Only an indirect approach will work.